# How can I set a Flatpickr theme dynamically?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I am using flatpickr in a Vue 3 project and would like the user to able to change the theme dynamically. [Using](https://flatpickr.js.org/themes/#available-themes):

```
require("flatpickr/dist/themes/material_blue.css");
```

will set the theme to material_blue, but if the theme is then changed within the project, for example:

```
require("flatpickr/dist/themes/material_red.css");
```

the previous css file remains (presumably cached) and the new theme is not applied.

How do I get around this? I have looked at 'unrequiring' but can't get this to work.

UPDATE:

Achieved with this:

Initialising with a default theme in the index file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/themes/dark.css" />
```

and if it changed:

```
  var stylesheet = document.head.querySelector("link[href*='themes']");
  stylesheet.href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/themes/" + myNewTheme + ".css";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you they are doing it on their website

There is a script [themer.js](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr.github.io/blob/master/static/themer.js) which is handling the changes:

In this script the `link` element is accessed first

```
stylesheet = document.head.querySelector("link[href$='flatpickr.css']"),
```

And then when the theme is changed, the `href` attribute of that style is changed

```
stylesheet.href =
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/themes/" +
  e.target.value +
  ".css";
```

Which unloads the old css and loads new one

Comment: Really helpful - thanks. Updated question with my answer.